# What is the simplest logic to create new column in dataframe from old column that modifies value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm mostly R user but I am switching to Python in some use cases and I have very trivial task to do that involves cleaning of values/data preparation.

I have a dataframe with values that are in raw format and based on the values, I want to create a new column with clean values, using function like string.replace()

Let's create a dummy table:

```
import pandas as pd
dummy_table = pd.DataFrame(data = ["London - City", "Manchester - City"], columns = ["City_raw"])

dummy_table
           City_raw
0      London - City
1  Manchester - City
```

In R, I would use a very simple and straightforward logic to create a new column with modified original value.

```
dummy_table$City_clean <- gsub(" - City", "", dummy_table$City_raw)
```

And the result would be:

```
       City_raw       City_clean
0  London - City      London
1  Manchester - City  Manchester
```

I want to keep both columns, original and new modified.
What I tried was using this syntax in Python:

```
dummy_table['City_clean'] = dummy_table['City_raw'].replace(" - City",  "", inplace = False)
```

But the resulting table had new column with the same values as Original column, meaning there was no replacement done, only copying of values.

```
       City_raw       City_clean
0  London - City      London - City 
1  Manchester - City  Manchester - City
```

My question is: Is there some simple straightforward syntax that would do vectorized (operation on all values of a column) operations on column and create a new column or do I need to get fancy in Python and use some kind of apply / lambda functions?

I would also appreciate some explanation of why it works in R and not in Python, or what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need `regex=True` in [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
dummy_table['City_clean'] = dummy_table['City_raw'].replace(" - City",  "", regex = True)
print (dummy_table)
            City_raw  City_clean
0      London - City      London
1  Manchester - City  Manchester
```

Or better:

```
dummy_table['City_clean'] = dummy_table['City_raw'].replace("\s*-\s*City",  "", regex = True)
print (dummy_table)
            City_raw  City_clean
0      London - City      London
1  Manchester - City  Manchester
```

Comment: Do you think this is the simplest and the most straightforward solution? I accepted your answer, because it was the closest to what I posted even though you both are correct. Thanks.

Comment: If need replace, then yes, if need extract data, then better is split.

Answer (score 5):

we can use [Series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) method and then access first element of a list for each row, using [.str[0] accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
In [43]: dummy_table['City_clean'] = dummy_table.City_raw.str.split('\s*-\s*').str[0]

In [44]: dummy_table
Out[44]:
            City_raw  City_clean
0      London - City      London
1  Manchester - City  Manchester
```

Step by step:

```
In [50]: dummy_table.City_raw.str.split('\s*-\s*')
Out[50]:
0        [London, City]
1    [Manchester, City]
Name: City_raw, dtype: object

In [51]: dummy_table.City_raw.str.split('\s*-\s*').str[0]
Out[51]:
0        London
1    Manchester
Name: City_raw, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please describe how the syntax works? What does .str[0] mean? It splits the string at every space and returns the first part?

Comment: @StefanK, i've extended my answer with an explanation